# All my WP sites load extremely slow on Google Chrome but only when logged in

Tags: performance, wordpress, google-chrome, authentication

I have noticed that when my internet connection is a bit slower all my wp sites take up to five minutes to load Google Chrome when I am logged in. The version of google chrome I am using is 17.0.963.83.

When I logout the site loads fine again. The dashboard also loads fine when I am logged in and I know it's not a problem with my theme because the same thing happens applies when I apply the default twenty eleven theme.

I have set up a dummy subscriber user so you can test it yourself (to see the difference between the logged in states you need a slow connection though :p)

[h2euro.org/wp-admin](http://h2euro.org/wp-admin)
u: testuser
p: test

Does anybody have an idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

When logged in, it loads "aloha.js", which is almost a megabyte. Found using Chrome's dev tools, 'network' pane.

Comment: Thanks, not sure why I was never notified of this answer. Learned a lot these last five years so pretty embarrassing to see the original question now haha.